# Multiple .NET Host Running in UnrealEditor

Tags: unreal, .net

Unreal Editor has 64+ services running under it with .Net host and console window host running multiple times. I am running Unreal Engine 5.3.2 source build. I have tried recompiling and redownloading the source several times with the same effect. How to get rid of those many process of .NET running, which are making my system laggy?

[image]

Comment: This might be a support question to direct to Unreal's customer support channels or bug reporting systems.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally caution you against thinking any specific process is causing your system to be "laggy" without a good reason for assuming so.

Your computer is running tens of thousands of concurrent threads all the time. A handful of (what appear to be) internal processes for Unreal are not likely to be introducing any load into your system. (For example don't ever look at `chrome.exe` it is frightening)

You do seem to have some memory pressure, increasing the amount of RAM in your system is an option assuming you have the time and resources to do so, but this still may not solve your problem.

There are dozens of factors which could cause your system to feel slow. Those processes *could* be the reason. I would recommend filing a support ticket with the owners of the tooling directly as recommended in the comments if you want to know more about specifically those processes.

In general if your system is running at 80-90% memory utilization you are potentially going to run into hiccups.

Comment: I asked my friend and he only has 4 process running as a child of unreal in task manger my  Ram is 32Gb and i9, i think that's more then enough to run an empty project i think. i download the binary version and its running perfectly with only 4 process running inside unreal its some kind of bug from MS or Epic Idk.